# How to make shares only mount for particular users?

Tags: mount, fstab, nfs

How can I set up shares to conditionally mount depending on which user logged in?

I have some shares on a NAS that I put in fstab, and the line in fstab looks like this:

`192.168.1.101:/volume1/data   /media/data    nfs defaults 0 0`

Now they mount automatically when I log into my computer (gnome-shell on ubuntu 12.10), and that's nice.  However they also mount automatically when other users login, and I don't want that.

Comment: ACL may be your answer. See here: http://askubuntu.com/a/52710/3940

Comment: I don't have the answer for you but I'd like to warn you about this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1084188