# How to set permissions for shared folders

Tags: server, permissions, shared-folders

I could use some help setting permissions for a series of shared folders. Say I have the following three folders:

```
/xfer/joe
/xfer/bob
/xfer/sam
```

Joe should be able to read, write and delete files from `/xfer/joe`, and list, write but not read files from `/xfer/bob` and `/xfer/sam`. Likewise, Bob should be able to read, write, delete files from `/xfer/bob`, but only list and write (not read) from `/xfer/joe` and `/xfer/sam`.

I can `chmod` and `chown` the folders, but how to set up so if Bob drops a file into Joe, Joe retains ownership of the file.

The users will sftp files in and out of the folders.

Comment: You probably do not mean "write" but "create new files"? Since writing to a file means being able to append and remove content from a file ... and thus also includes deleting and reading (when someone can write a file he can empty it and so can delete contents of it; effectively removing it except for the file name itself).

Comment: Also: you did not specify how these shares are set up. IF this is through FTP or Samba you might need to set permissions in the config file that comes with that software.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ACL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#ACL_.28Access_Control_List.29). It is capable of creating more refined permissions than chown/chmod.The [Eiciel package](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/eiciel) allows GUI access to ACLs through the Nautilus file manager.

[image]

- [setfacl](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html) - set file access control lists
- [getfacl](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/getfacl1.html) - get file access control lists

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/shared-folders-for-all-users for command line ACL setup.