# Permission on shared folder are correct but files can't be saved

Tags: permissions, samba, shared-folders

I have a shared folder set up on an ubuntu machine. When someone connects to the folder and creates a file, the file permissions set the group to read/write. I can check the permission on Ubuntu or Windows and they both show the group has read/write permission.

The problem comes when a user tries to edit a file created by another user. For example, user1 creates a text document. If user2 connects to the shared folder they can open the text document but when they try to save the file there is an error saying they don't have permission. Each user is also a part of the same group.

My samba.conf file addition looks like this:

```
[foldername]
    page = /home/path/to/directory
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    valid users = user1, user2, user3, user4
```

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/shared-folders-for-all-users

Comment: Thanks Jacob. That's actually the process I went through to set up the shared folder. When a file is created inside the shared folder the permission show up as being correct but a user outside of the creator is not able to make edits to the created file.

Comment: @user715564 How have you created the share (with Nautilus, Personal File sharing, ...)?

Comment: I created a folder on the desktop set it be a shared folder and set up samba to allow access to each user. I am using acl to assign created files/folders to be set under the group that each user is in.

Comment: doesn't work, still access denied, I have full 777 permissions locally and in the share settings.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to set the "setgid" bit on your shared directory. This means that all files/directories created in the shared dir will automatically belong to the group. Like this:

```
chmod g+s <directory name>
```

You may also have to do this on existing subdirectories. In the future, when new directories are created, the setgid bit will automatically be turned on for them.

Comment: doesn't work, did this on all dirs

Comment: @Sephethus Looks like there must be another problem with your Samba configuration. This answer is showing how to ensure that all files created in the shared directory will belong to the same group that owns the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it out according to this [simple tutorial](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/305771-quick-and-dirty-samba-setup) ("quick 'n dirty") and I think it cannot miss, it works perfectly for all users (I tried). The key is

```
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
```

...which will take care of the permissions in the way you want it.

Comment: This gives rwx permissions to all authenticated users on the server. Not so great unless you can trust everyone with a login and putty/ssh.

Comment: @outisnihil true of course, but that seems obvious.

Comment: doesn't work, added this to the share settings, no change, still access denied.