# How do i create a partition, so all users can read wrie execute files without any permissions?

Tags: 12.04, users, partitioning, shared-folders

I have a 160 GB hard drive and i need to create a separate partition so all users can access the files (mostly music, movies, pictures), without requiring any authentication from the administrator or other users.

BTW i'm new to Ubuntu

Comment: Is access from Windows needed too? Otherwise see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/shared-folders-for-all-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create a partition using **Gparted**. I recommend you to format it with **NTFS** (it will not be much fragmented since it will hold only big media files, unlike C drive. **fat32** on the ,other hand, will not allow to copy/save files larger than 5GB. Also NTFS can be mounted when in windows)
- Open up **Disk** program from dash. click on the partition and then click on gear icon below (as shown)

[image: Disk program ubuntu]

you will get many options, click on **Edit mount option**.

- a small window will open then toggle **Automatic mount option** to **OFF**
- if you want to change the location of mounting, give a path in **mount location** ( i recommend mouting in /media folder this will make the mounted partition to appear on side in nautilus). you can also change the name by which it will be mounted in **Identify as** ( i recommend using label)
- then press OK.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a fat32 partition work for viewing media and writing new media, since fat32 doesn't save any owner permissions? May be a problem for executing a file, since it doesn't save executable permissions either, but it sounds like you won't actually be storing executable files there, just media (movies, pics, etc).

Or for a permissions-aware FS (like ext) making a group containing all the wanted users, then giving that group rwx permissions for the folders in question should work... (may have trouble with new folders though, not sure there)