# Cannot write on ext4 partition Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, ext4

I formatted the disk in my computer as ext4. Now I'm trying to make it readable and writable for any user on this computer.
My entries in /etc/fstab look like this

```
# Data partitions
UUID=f59da30c-a2a8-4cab-97c6-4476453a3a31   /media/data1    ext4    defaults    0   0
UUID=73f1dad6-dcc4-4d12-996b-5e62406e7881   /media/data2    ext4    defaults    0   0
```

After mounting I also changed the owner of the mounted drives and gave rw permissions to every user as shown below. However other users still cannot write to that partition.

```
$ sudo mount -a 
$ sudo chown -R :users /media/data* 
$ sudo chmod -R g+rw /media/data* 
$ cd /media/data1/
$ touch test 
touch: cannot touch ‘test’: Permission denied


$ ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Mär 18 19:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root  4096 Mär 18 19:11 ../
drwxr-x---+  2 root root  4096 Dez 15 18:15 cvg/
drwxrwxr-x   2 cvg  users 4096 Mär 18 19:18 data1/
drwxrwxr-x   2 cvg  users 4096 Mär 18 19:18 data2/
```

(what is strange is that data1 and data2 are not highlighted green in bash after mounting, which was the case when I mounted patitions on other computers).

I already did this on another computer so I don't understand what I did wrong this time :(.

Comment: First, on directories you need to also set the x bit, so chmod 770 . Second shared directories are not always so simple as new files will not have proper ownership / permissions. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/shared-folders-for-all-users

Comment: Are the data1 and data2 partitions already mounted at /media/cvg/(UUID for data1) and /media/cvg/(UUID for data2)? The default when plugging a USB drive is to mount at media/username/UUID... I always mount to /srv for partitions I intend to share like this. This might be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Is current user in your group "users" ? Try `groups` command. If its not, than use `sudo adduser USER-NAME users` and then reload your session.
- Isn't `/media/data1/test` file already there (owned by someone else)? Try `ll /media/data1/test`.
- Are those partitions mounted without any restrictions? Try `mount|grep /media/data` command.

Mind to share outputs of these?

P.S. In your `/etc/fstab` you set last parameter to `0`, meaning the drives wont be checked by `fsck` at system start when needed, are you OK with this?

Comment: Might be that my current user is not part of the "users" group. Although I cannot understand why? I tried creating users via terminal "adduser" and via gui "user accounts". In both cases there is no option to assign a group to a user. Anyway 1) here my output of groups: "MYCURRENTUSERNAME adm sudo lpadmin sambashare". 2) I'm setting up a new computer so there is definitely no file "test". 3) mount|grep /media/data gives
/dev/sdb1 on /media/data1 type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/data2 type ext4 (rw)
 4) (PS) yes I fear that the check fails and thus my computer gets stuck while booting

Comment: You need to add 'your user' to group 'users' by `sudo adduser YOUR-USER users`, then you need to reload your session (logout and login again to desktop or switch to this group for this particular terminal by `newgrp users`).

Comment: Command `adduser` has `--ingroup` option to specify additional group membership while creating user, but `adduser USER GROUP` works fine as well.