# How do I override ACL permissions for single files or directories?

Tags: permissions, acl

To share data (audio, video, pictures, documents) between all users on my desktop I created an ACL for a dedicated shared partition on my hard drive [according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/52710/3940) which I mount at boot via `fstab` using the option `acl`.

This works great as all users (me, wife, kids, and our media center PC) can now access those shared files having read and write access.

Now there are a few files within those shared directories I do not want the kids and the media PC to have read access to, but my wife still should be able to read and write to them.

I know that I could create another restricted directory with a different ACL to hold these files but for the sake of backups and for easy retrieving those files in our custom directory structure (pictures and documents are stored according to topics or creation date) I would prefer to not move them somewhere else.

Is there another way to override the ACL permissions for single subdirectories, or files?