# Samba users cannot write into folders that created by other users

Tags: samba

If one of users create a folder, other users have no permission to write into it. How can I solve this problem ?

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================
[global]
create mask =0777
directory mask = 0777
workgroup = ENERJIK
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   dns proxy = no
#### Debugging/Accounting ####
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
  syslog = 0
  panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
####### Authentication #######
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n 
   map to guest = bad user
############ Misc ############
   usershare allow guests = yes
#======================= Share Definitions =======================
 [printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

[Aylik Denetim Bilgisi]
   comment = Enerjik Yapı Denetim Dosya Paylaşım Alanı
   path = /media/depo/Aylikdenetimbilgisi
   browseable = yes
   write list = emre fatmanur ulfet
   guest ok = no

[Çalışan Takip]
   comment = Enerjik Yapı Denetim Dosya Paylaşım Alanı
   path = /media/depo/Calisantakip
   browseable = yes
   write list = emre fatmanur ulfet
   guest ok = no

[Inşaat Takip]
   comment = Enerjik Yapı Denetim Dosya Paylaşım Alanı
   path = /media/depo/Insaattakip
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   browseable = yes
   write list = emre fatmanur ulfet
   guest ok = no


[Ruhsatlı Projeler]
   comment = Enerjik Yapı Denetim Dosya Paylaşım Alanı
   path = /media/depo/Ruhsatliprojeler
   browseable = yes
   write list = emre murat eren servet nuri
   guest ok = no

[Enerjik]
   comment = Enerjik Yapı Denetim Dosya Paylaşım Alanı
   path = /media/depo/EnerjikYD
   browseable = yes
   write list = emre ulfet fatmanur
   valid users = emre ulfet fatmanur
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   guest ok = no
[c$]
   comment = Kök dizin paylaşımı
   path = /
   browseable = no
   read only = no
   write list = root
```

Answer (score 1):

`create mask` only defines the maximum rights a file **can** be created with. If the windows user creates a file with 0750, that's the right that's going to be applied with your settings, since it's being bitwise ANDed. You probably want to combine your settings with the `force (directory) create mode = 0777` setting.

For more info check `man 5 smb.conf`:
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#CREATEMASK

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of problem is user permissions. When I used Active Control  List ([How do I set up a folder so that anything created in it inherits permissions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/shared-folders-for-all-users)), problem has been solved partially.  But now if one user create a folder, others cannot delete it but they can write into it.