# Definitive permission to folder

Tags: permissions, chmod

I'm giving full permission in a folder using chmod:

```
chmod 777 /srv/folder
```

Inside this folder many other folders and files will be created. My problem is that the full permission does no apply to these new folders and files. When I run the chmod command everything works OK, but after, when someone create a new file or folder this new item throws access denied error.

How can I set the permission in a way that everyone can do anything inside this folder, without having to update the permission?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If the users are all in the same group, you can use 'chmod g+s /path/to/directory' to set the new files and folders created to belong to the same group as the parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shared folders for all users](http://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/shared-folders-for-all-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
chmod g+s /srv/folder
```

This will sticky the group permission of any new files to that of the parent - if I understand correctly what you want to do.

Comment: not a problem, happy coding.