# How to allow FTP users to access my secondary hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, users, ftp, vsftpd, user-management

I'm using ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS.

I installed Ubuntu on my main drive (275GB m.2) and everything was working fine. Few days ago I installed another internal disk (2TB Western Digital) and installed VSFTPD in attempt to creating an FTP server so my surveillance camera can record on it.

I managed to "successfully" create the FTP and the cameras can reach it and record on it. The problem is it recording in the 275GB m.2 disk not the 2TB Western Digital.

I checked and I found the only User1 which is the user I used to mount and format the 2TB disk able to access this disk. Other uses can't access is.

So to clarify:
1- How can I allow all users to access my 2TB disk? Is there is a way to allow FTP users to access only the 2TB disk or only a specific folder inside the 2TB disk without giving them permission to access everything else?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: How did you mount the disk?  Did you create an entry in fstab?

Comment: Sharing a data drive with all users can easily [be done using ACL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/how-do-i-set-up-a-folder-so-that-anything-created-in-it-inherits-permissions).

Comment: You can do this via the `vsftp` configuration. Please have a look at [the man page](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html), especially the part on `chroot` and `anonymous` users. Depends on what you mean by "all users": All defined users, or all users that have any network access to the server?

Comment: I don't exactly remember how do i mount the disk. I think I open "Disk" tool and formatted then mounted the disk.

What I mean by all users is "User1" which I created when installed Ubuntu, User2, User3 ---> User10 which I created for my cameras with this command "sudo useradd -m USER -s /usr/sbin/nologin". I followed this "https://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/how-do-i-set-up-a-folder-so-that-anything-created-in-it-inherits-permissions" to create the FTP server.